# Multiple types of accounts in meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

Here is the scenario:

There are two types of users: user one and user two. user two has more privileges

When someone wants to sign up to my website he can choose to be user one or user two in signup template (radio buttons) .

if he/she choose user one, a user record will be created in the database and he/she can use limited functions.

If he/she choose user two, a user record will be created and it will be disabled (can't login) until the admin approve the account. Then he/she can use the full functions of the website.

the questions is how to implement it using accounts:ui package if it is possible.

Comment: I would highly recommend you to write the form for user management instead of configuring accounts:ui. For your scenario if the user select the checkbox set a boolean to true,then in serverside while creating the user check the boolean if it is there don't allow him to login until he/she gets the confirmation email. Take a look at  [Account.onCreateUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser), [Meteor.loginWithPassword](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser).

Comment: http://steve-adams.me/practical-examples-of-authentication-in-meteor-1-0/ and http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/41741539120/building-a-customized-accounts-ui-for-meteor. These two article would help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own additions on top of Meteor's standard accounts system by storing extra fields on Users collection's objects, such as "role" or "privileges", etc.

Or you can use a package that already covers a lot of common cases like [this roles package](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles).